# MySQL search on multiple items with from-to values

Tags: php, mysql, search

I need to search multiple items with from-to values. How can I do this?

I have my database with these values, for example:

```
ITEMS          VALUES
Estado         Zulia
Ciudad         Maracaibo
Habitaciones   4
Baños          3
Precio         100000
```

I know how to search for simple values (like Estado and Zulia) because I'm looking for only one value. But with Habitaciones, Baños and Precio I need to search from-to values. For example, Habitaciones from 3 to 5, Baños from 1 to 3, Precio from 80000 to 200000. And have results with all that match those values.

Of course if something does not match (for example Precio from 110000 to 200000) nothing is returned.

How can I do this, please? Some examples would be appreciated!

Comment: Are the ITEMS you're talking about fields in a table?  What is the table called?

Answer (score 1):

You use [BETWEEN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between).
For example

```
SELECT * FROM Items WHERE Banos BETWEEN 1 AND 3 AND Precio BETWEEN 1000 AND 5000;
```

Comment: `Banos` **is not** a field name

Comment: @zerkms You think those are separate tables? I thought those were the fields in his table.

Comment: I think they are just values of `ITEMS` column :-S Well indeed it looks strange :-S

Comment: Just What I needed.!! Just one last question, this part of the code

WHERE Banos BETWEEN 1 AND 3 AND Precio BETWEEN 1000 AND 5000;

Does not need to separate by (), like

WHERE (Banos BETWEEN 1 AND 3) AND (Precio BETWEEN 1000 AND 5000);

It is just to clear doubts.!

Thanks for the help.! xD

Comment: @user998802: nope. Parentheses in this case could increase readability but don't change anything in results/behaviour

Comment: @zerkms What about a "plus that" value.?? I mean, in this case I have BETWEEN Values, but, I would like to look for plus that XXX Value.. Maybe WHERE Banos > 4..??? Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE values BETWEEN 3 AND 5
```

This will return all the records where `values` field value is between 3 and 5 inclusively.

Comment: Thanks a lot.!! And if i need to use more than one "between" I need to use () to separate.?? Something like this:

WHERE (Banos BETWEEN 1 AND 3) AND (Precio BETWEEN 1000 AND 5000)